# Splitting a polygon into a number of equal areas

Tags: python, polygon

I store many polygons in the following format: `[[37.5362548828125,55.69286346435547],[37.53067398071289,55.68980407714844],[37.539642333984375,55.684783935546875],[37.544471740722656,55.68798828125]]`.
I need to divide them into equal hexagons to achieve something like this:
 [image]

Are there any solutions that can do this or may do the similar thing like dividing area into any other shapes?

Comment: Why hexagon, why not plain squares?

Comment: Are these coordinates on an infinite flat plane or on the surface of something more exotic (e.g. a quasi-spherical object like earth)? In either case, the class of algorithms you're looking for are called **polygonal tilings**, and you'll probably find more results at gis.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @sagarr solution that does it with plain squares will help a lot :)

Comment: @HansMusgrave It's an infinite flat plane. Will try to find something at gis.stackexchange.com, thank you

Comment: may be this help then: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/54119/92993